# Stored Procedure table security

Tags: oracle, security, stored-procedures

We want to grant a user `execute` on a stored procedure which will access certain tables, but prevent that same user from performing a direct query on the same tables.

Here is our current model.  User `foo` is the owner of the stored procedures.  It has direct select, insert, update, and delete privileges on all the necessary tables.  The stored procedures have been created with `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`.  `Foo` grants `execute` on its stored procedures to user `bar`.

User `bar` calls the stored procedures via the grants above.  By design, it has no ability to change the source code of any stored procedures.  It has access via a role to the necessary tables.

So far, that works fine.  Now we have a new requirement.  A new user must be created that can execute the stored procedures, but cannot directly query against the tables (via SQLPlus, JDBC, ODBC, etc.)

I can't see any obvious way to implement this.  All suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the procedures that `foo` owns were defined as `authid definer`, the default, then callers would not need privileges on the underlying tables in order to execute the stored procedures.  Normally, that is how privileges are managed in Oracle.  It is somewhat uncommon to use `authid current_user` stored procedures because that forces the caller to have privileges on the stored procedure in addition to privileges on the underlying table.

You'll either need to modify your existing procedures so that they are definer's rights stored procedures or you'll need to create a separate set of definer's rights stored procedures that you give the new user access to.